# Sending SMS using Way2sms on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms, way2sms

Can any one help me to send sms using way2sms api by means of rails application.

Thanks

Comment: You have to add more details to your question. Please add the description of the problems encountered.

Comment: how to send sms through rails application using way2sms api

Answer (score 2):

I have developed an API that anyone can use. Check it out [here](http://ubaid.tk/sms/).

You can use the web page I created or you can use the API. For example, your application can directly forward the request to:

http://ubaid.tk/sms/sms.aspx?uid=99999xxxxx&pwd=12345&msg=YOUR_SMS_MESSAGE&phone=9996669990&provider=way2sms

The different providers are way2sms, fullonsms, smsinside and tezsms.

Works 100%, all the time. :)

Edit: As of 2014, the service is stopped since it violates the TOS of most of these providers.

Cheers.

Comment: Do I need any license to use this API? (Hope u r having way2sms and others' license as well ;) )

Comment: you dont need any license to use this API. Its basically automating your task, reducing your efforts.

Comment: s this app u developed is open source

Comment: Its not open source. Its free to use. I had developed it for me once upon a time. Now i have given access to everyone to use the api.

Comment: hope you are not storing credentials ;)

Comment: I think you should look at the way2sms TOS, they make it clear that they collect personal information. If you are so worried about security then I'd recommend that you don't use such services.

Comment: ubaid.tk have been very reliable API, but nowadays its not working

Comment: its not working. response will be '-1' . Can you please share something which can send sms to mobile number. pleasure for your responce

Comment: Have fixed few API's now. Way2sms and 160by2 will no more work since they block the IP's of my server..

Answer (score 2):

I have created a free open source SMS API called **AlfaSMS API** for way2sms,160by2.com,fullonsms.   It is available in many programming languages like PHP,VB,C++,c#,Python etc.You can download it from http://www.alfredfrancis.in/alfasms-api/

Answer (score 0):

There is a ruby gem that I wrote based on Ubaid's API. You can find it [here](https://github.com/nikhilbhardwaj/chagol).
You can use it in any ruby or rails project as long as you are running a version of ruby >= 1.9.

```
require 'chagol'
texter = Chagol::SmsSender("9876543210","password","way2sms")
texter.send("9968154700", "Chagol Rocks")
```

Disclaimer, I am the author of this gem.